# A newbie question about Calender app development

Tags: iphone, calendar

I'm newbie to iphone. am going to develop calender app. please suggest me which is possible and easiest way to develop calender in tamil version, either WebView or normal view.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calendar in iphone app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634000/calendar-in-iphone-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://blog.webscale.co.in/?p=244.check this out !

Comment: hi Swastik, thanks for the information... its really helpful to me...